# Android: How to display transparent loading layer above the activity

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, preloading

I have tested 2 methods to display a transparent loading layer (progress bar) above the activity but activity content gets hidden here's the first one:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center" >

  <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the other method with style

```
<RelativeLayout
  style="@style/GenericProgressBackground"
  android:id="@+id/loadingPanel">
  <ProgressBar
    style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<style name="GenericProgressBackground" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:background">#DD111111</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
<style name="GenericProgressIndicator"  arent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>
```

And hide or display it

```
findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

(Both are added as the first item inside the root view)

But both methods hide the activity and I want to be visible semi-transparent like the image below how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Create a Custom Dialog for this . This way it will be reusable and you will not have to worry about back button click .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your lay out code here-->

</LinearLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />


</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: don't required to create any thing new, simply make like this

Comment: In this solution, background attribute is showing black solid color, Use ARGB format instead of RGB. Something like #77000000

Comment: why are use argb? here

Comment: to show the translucent layer with alpha, otherwise, the progress layer would be opaque

Comment: please check know, know i think, may be solved your issue

Comment: Hi Hitesh Tarbundiya, in your xml, for LinearLayout rectify the value of background attribute like this: android:background="#77000000"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189664/discussion-between-mithil1501-and-hitesh-tarbundiya).

Comment: works great but how to replace the default animation with an animated image?

Comment: Using Glide and a URL of an animated image and set ImageView instead of ProgressBar but the question now is how to save an animated image with the app not online as Android Studio doesn't accept such images in drawable

Comment: i think you told, like gif. you want to use gif in your progressbar?

Comment: If you say yes, then i will give you one more class and library that support gif image.

Comment: This work great. I did some changes & added black color drawable to the background & changed its alpha value & made nice transparent progress dialog.

Answer (score 4):

**Thank me later**

1. create style *LoadingDialogTheme*

   ```
   <style name="LoadingDialogTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
       <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. create color:

```
<color name="dark_overlay">#B3000000</color>
```

3. create layout *layout_dialog.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/dark_overlay"
       android:id="@+id/loading_container">
   
       <ProgressBar
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
   
   </RelativeLayout>
```

4. extend Dialog *LoadingDialog*

```
    open class LoadingDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context, R.style.LoadingDialogTheme) {
        private val mContext: Context = context
    
         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            val inflater = mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val inflateView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog, findViewById(R.id.loading_container))
             setCancelable(false)
            setContentView(inflateView)
        }
    
    }
```

5. use it

```
val loader = LoadingDialog(requireContext()) // <-- context
loader.show()
```

Comment: mContext will lead to memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i forgot to add class.

you can try this,

```
public class LoadingDialog extends Dialog {
    private Context mContext;

    public LoadingDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View inflateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.loading_cont));
        setContentView(inflateView);
    }

}
```

add this layout loading_dialog :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loading_cont"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_dialog_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/login_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
        </ProgressBar>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

after that add in your class

```
LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(this);
loadingDialog.show();
```

Comment: and the style please? AlertDialogCustom

Comment: No need for that,by mistake it remains to delete.Regards.